# Coding a Popover segue for a custom UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a custom `UIButton` which I defined programmatically like this:

```
self.hard1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.hard1 setFrame:CGRectMake(884, 524, 105, 60)]; // set the x,y,width and height
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.jpg"];
self.hard1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.hard1.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.hard1 addTarget: self
          action: @selector(buttonTapped:)
forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.hard1 setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:self.hard1];
```

As a result of that, it doesn't show in the Interface Builder, it only comes on the screen when I run the app. This means I can't ctrl + drag from the `UIButton` to a `ViewController` to select a popover segue. Can I call a segue within my code? If not, are there any other options for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blub's and tkanzakic's answers won't quite work, as a popover segue insists on having an anchor view in the storyboard when you create the segue. And as your button doesn't yet exist it will be tricky to get that right. You could anchor to an existing storyboard view, but then the popover arrow won't point to the right object when it pops over. You could move that existing view around in code to match the rect of your code-created button. But you might as well dispense with the segue altogether and perform the popover in code.

You will need to declare a popoverController property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController* buttonPopoverController;
```

Then your button action can look something like this:

```
- (void) buttonTapped:(UIButton*) sender
{
    ContentViewController* contentVC = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
    self.buttonPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                     initWithContentViewController:contentVC];
    self.buttonPopoverController.delegate = self;  
           //only required if using delegate methods

    [self.buttonPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame
                           inView:self.view
         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                         animated:YES];
}
```

The ContentViewController is whichever view controller you are intending to segue to. If it is configured using a storyboard scene, you may want to do something like this when you create it:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
 ContentViewController* contentVC = 
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentViewController"];
```

You can set the storyboard identifier using the Identity Inspector when you have the relevant view controller selected in the storyboard.

Comment: I've got this error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'ContentViewController'; did you mean '_parentViewController'?`

Comment: @LouisHolley, "ContentViewController" should be changed to whatever type your viewController is that you want to put in the popoverController. The popoverController is not the destination viewController, it is a container into which you place your required viewController when you alloc/init.

Comment: That seems to work nicely. Unfortunately I cannot test it because I've got one of those annoying signal SIGABRT exceptions. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The exception is here: `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentViewController"];`

Comment: @LouisHolley You need to  give the relevant viewController in your storyboard an identifier which should be matched to the string you use in `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` (eg @"ContentViewController",but you can call it anything you like). You do this using the Identity Insepector once you have selected the viewController in the storyboard (it's very similar to giving a Segue an identifier in your storyboard so that you can refer to it in code)

Comment: I did enter 'ContentViewController' into the identifier of my view controller. It still seems to be giving an exception

Comment: @LouisHolley Thats really odd because it shouldn't, if (a) you replace the first line of the buttonTapped method with the two lines lower down in my solution for yanking the viewController out of the storyboard; and (b) the identifier in the storyboard exactly matches the identifier in the `instantiateViewController` method. Are you sure you put it in the "Storyboard ID" and not the "Restoration ID"?

Comment: Ah that would be why. I put it in the Restoration ID. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. CTRL + drag a segue from the *ViewController that contains your
   Button* --> *ViewController you want to segue to*
2. Secify an identifier (just some unique string) for that segue (
   with the segue selected, open the righthand "*Utilities*" sidebar
   and open it's "*Attributes inspector*" tab
3. Add `[self
   performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifierStringYouSecifiedInStep2" sender:sender];`
   inside your `- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender` method ! )

Comment: I'm getting two errors. One of which is `No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier'` and the other is `Popover segue with no anchor`

Comment: sorry, forgot the sender argument, edited it now, but just follow XCodes autocomplete to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

in the process of creation of the button you are assigning it an action associate to a method called `buttonTapped:`, you can perform the segue from there, something like this:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"theSegueIdentifier" sender:sender];
}
```